# Generators in Chicken Scheme

Tags: scheme, chicken-scheme

This code works in the Racket Scheme provided at [codepad.org](http://codepad.org/2K8TPKn9), displaying the numbers 1, 2 and 3 on successive lines before displaying the message "unexpected return", but the same exact code fails using Chicken Scheme at [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/mlICuf), and I don't understand the error message that Chicken Scheme provides. How can I make it work with Chicken Scheme?

```
(define-syntax define-generator
  (lambda (x)
    (syntax-case x (lambda)
      ((stx name (lambda formals e0 e1 ...))
         (with-syntax ((yield (datum->syntax-object (syntax stx) 'yield)))
           (syntax (define name
             (lambda formals
               (let ((resume #f) (return #f))
                 (define yield
                   (lambda args
                     (call-with-current-continuation
                      (lambda (cont)
                        (set! resume cont)
                        (apply return args)))))
                 (lambda ()
                   (call-with-current-continuation
                    (lambda (cont)
                      (set! return cont)
                      (cond (resume (resume))
                      (else (let () e0 e1 ...)
                            (error 'name "unexpected return"))))))))))))
        ((stx (name . formals) e0 e1 ...)
          (syntax (stx name (lambda formals e0 e1 ...)))))))

(define-generator (test-gen)
  (yield 1)
  (yield 2)
  (yield 3))

(define t (test-gen))
(display (t)) (newline)
(display (t)) (newline)
(display (t)) (newline)
(display (t)) (newline)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chicken requires the [`syntax-case` egg](http://wiki.call-cc.org/eggref/3/syntax-case) to be loaded in order to support `syntax-case`. However, ideone does not have that egg installed, so you can't use it there.

So, in order to test on ideone, you're going to have to convert your macro to an explicit-renaming one.

Comment: Correction: ideone runs CHICKEN 4.9, for which the syntax-case egg is not available (it is a legacy CHICKEN 3 egg).

Comment: @sjamaan Thanks for the correction! Is there a way to use `syntax-case` in 4.9, and if so, how?

Comment: @chris-jester-young Unfortunately, there is (currently) no way to do so. syntax-case is incredibly hairy. There are only two portable implementations for it, and both subsume the entire macro and module system of your Scheme. This means you can't use them unless you allow them to take over everything. We used the psyntax implementation in CHICKEN 3 which was okay because CHICKEN 3 had no module/macro system of its own. It may be possible to implement syntax-case using ER/IR macros in CHICKEN but nobody has dared to try it yet.